# Why does custom font appears only after few milliseconds when starting app? Render problem? - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, textview, font-family, google-fonts

I have an app with a splash screen followed by the main activity with some TextViews in it.
I'm using font family "aladin" which I have choosen from *Attributes > fontFamily > More Fonts...* .

The problem is, when I start my app the splash screen appears correctly BUT when my main activity follows, for a millisecond you can see that the font in my TextView is jumping from "default" to aladin.
In other words, it seems as if it takes too much time for the aladin font to render/load.

How can I fix this??
I have already played around with changing textsize from sp to dp but that doesn't solve my problem.

The aladin font should come up immediately, not after a millisecond, it just doesn't look nice.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"

        android:fontFamily="@font/aladin"

        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="26sp" />
```

**EDIT:**
here is part of my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
```

and here is part of my SplashActivity.java:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        };

        mHandler=new Handler();

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy (){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mHandler!=null && mRunnable !=null)
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you you delay displaying the splash screen until.the font has loaded?

Comment: @BanksySan I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly: I used DelayTime of 1500 as you can see now in my edited question. Is that helpful? Even after this delay the font still changes for a millisecond when Splashscreen disappears.

Comment: Having the same issue here!

@BanksySan, how can I know whether the font has loaded or not? is there a callback?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem; when the app starts, the text shows up in its default font for a fraction of a second, and then gets redrawn in the custom font. This probably won't bother most users, but it's definitely noticeable.

I also found out that once the custom font is loaded, the subsequent texts are drawn without showing the default font first.

So, the way I worked around is to load the custom font while the splash screen is showing. First, prepare the custom font.

1. res/font/ubuntu_mono.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
    app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs"
    app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
    app:fontProviderQuery="Ubuntu Mono">
</font-family>
```

2. res/value/preloaded_fonts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="preloaded_fonts" translatable="false">
        <item>@font/ubuntu_mono</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

3. AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
    ...

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
```

And then in the splash screen's layout, add a TextView with no text in it. This will load the custom font, and by the time the main shows up, the custom font will be ready.

4. res/layout/splash.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        ...

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            app:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_mono"             <-- custom font
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some fonts are large in size so they take some time to load i.e. a few milliseconds,
there is a simple solution which is to load the fonts programmatically before they appear in the UI by creating an instance of Typeface class  :
For example if you are going to use a specific font called "aladin" do the following :

```
//First you need to initialize and hook your textview
TextView textView;
textView = findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);

//initialize the font from ressources
Typeface typeFace = ResourcesCompat.getFont(getApplicationContext(),R.font.aladin);
//set the font to the textview
textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

Now you can avoid the delay that occurs when a custom font is loaded from a file. This is because the font is downloaded and cached by the font provider, so it can be accessed more quickly when needed.

Hope this has solved your problem :)